# LNK2019 Visual Community C++

Tags: c++

I've looked into a few questions of this topic already and most of the issues are that there is a reference that was not defined. However, my code here is incredibly simple so what I don't understand is what am I not defining here?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define RADIUS 5.257
#define PI 3.14159265
int main()
{
    double circleArea;
    circleArea = PI * RADIUS * RADIUS;
    cout << "\n\nThe area is " << circleArea << "\n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

EDIT: Sorry it would seem i forgot the full error code. Here it is:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Win32Project2, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>MSVCRTD.lib(crtexew.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup
1>D:\Win32Project2\Debug\Win32Project2.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: What's the full error message?

Comment: Doesn't the error message tell you which symbol is unresolved?

Comment: I've included the full error code into the question.

Answer (score 1):

You're compiling your program as a Windows application (that requires WinMain) and not a Console Application (that requires main).

Comment: Oh okay now I get it. I did start the project as a Console Application. Thanks for the answer.